# StartService() doesn't active onStartCommand() function (Manifest is correct)

Tags: java, android, xml, service, manifest

I'm trying to active my service with StartService(), and it should go next to the onStartCommand() function, but it doesn't. 
I tried many ways to not use the onStartCommand() function, but I need the information from the Intent in my service.
Here is the code:

MainAcitivty - OnCreate:

```
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    listTasks = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list_todo);

    loadTaskList();

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).setAction("Action", null).show();
            eventIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), NewEventActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(eventIntent, ADD_EVENT_REQUEST);
        }
    });

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("dbHelper", (Parcelable)dbHelper);
    if (!isMyServiceRunning(MyService.class))
    {
        startService(serviceIntent);
    }

}

//gets any service class and check if its alive (running)
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (ActivityManager.RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

MyService:

```
DBHelper dbHelper;

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    startServiceThread();
    super.onCreate();
}



@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {

        dbHelper = (DBHelper)extras.get("dbHelper");
    }
 return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}
```

Manifest:
(Here i also tried to add the service just with name=".MyService", but it did not change anything)

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:name=".MyApplication">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">

    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".NewEventActivity" />
    <activity android:name=".LockApp">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.example.user.project.MyService" />
</application>
```

Comment: "but it doesn't" -- how have you determined this? Have you tried getting rid of the unnecessary `isMyServiceRunning()` code? Are you perhaps crashing in `startServiceThread()`, considering that you are executing that code before `super.onCreate()`?

Comment: and what is `startService` returning in your case?

Comment: The isMyServiceRunning() code works fine(maybe unnecessary) but 
@CommonsWare   the function startService() is called.
It is crash in startServiceThread() because it can't get the information from the intent. Anyway, the onStartCommand() does not calls after the startService(). In the debugger, the startSerivce() be executed but the onStartCommand() isn't.

Answer (score 0):

> It is crash in startServiceThread() because it can't get the information from the intent

Then perhaps you should not be starting the thread until `onStartCommand()`.

> Anyway, the onStartCommand() does not calls after the startService()

That is because you are crashing on `onCreate()`. Stop crashing in `onCreate()`, and you should have better luck with `onStartCommand()`.

Comment: Thanks you very much!